# Open file dialog cannot show and application always crashes

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-10

Recently,the "open file dialog window" of some applications in my Windows 10 64bit system  cannot show,and the application always crashes,such as Visual Studio 2015 > File > Open > File >>>> Crash !,Visual Studio 2015 > Project > Add Existing Item >>>> Crash !, Excel 2016 > Open > Browse >>>> Crash!, Word 2016 > Open >Browse >>>>Crash!.
Even I created a simple winform application,and added only one "OpenFileDialog" control,and attempt to show it in onload event,It crashes too,the code and exception as bellow:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"D:\BaiduYunDownload";
        var file = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt
[image: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt]
Class not registered,shell32.dll?
[image: Class not registered,shell32.dll?]

Comment: Maybe test your ram with mdsched.exe. This is looking very strange.

Comment: Is this a 64bit app running on 32bit windows?

Comment: @NicolasTyler,my system is 64bit,and this  app will be good when I set the Project Property > Build > Platform target to "x64". The default "Any CPU" and "x32" will lead to the crash issue.

Comment: @C4u,Thanks for your advise,but I don't think this is a hardware issue,because when i startup my system in Security Mode,everything is ok.Look at the red circled error log,may be something wrong with the 
 shell32.dll of my OS.

Comment: @eforlina The only way to know is to run the app on a different machine. AccessViolationExceptions are usually from unsafe code (enabled in the project settings) or, as I asked in the previous comment, x64 running in x84.

Comment: @NicolasTyler Everything is ok on my friend's machine.I think this is an application independent issue ,because even the visual studio itself crashes too.

Comment: I had this problem today, affecting our own Wpf application and also notepad++, but I found the culprit like this: OpenFileDialog is a low level component in Windows, so error messages are logged here: Windows Event Viewer => "Windows Logs" => Application.  Sort by date descending. There I found an error mentioning our app, and also a DLL belonging to a well known cloud storage provider. I eventually uninstalled that provider's desktop application, and the problem went away. Try looking for mentions of third party DLLs in event viewer error log entries.

Comment: @Grubl3r Seems your are right,but I cannot verify your solution now. I have reinsalled my os  a fews months ago.You can  post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Seeing OpenFileDialog crash like this is not unusual on a dirty machine.  It loads a lot of shell extensions, programmers tend to have a lot of them and they are not exactly always stable.  What is unusual in this case is that you get very good debugging info about it.  combase.dll, oleaut32.dll and shell32.dll are the kind of OS modules that shell extensions need to get their job done.  But they don't come from c:\windows\syswow64 like they should, that's very, very bad.  Pretty hard to mess this up, this requires malware-like registry hacks.  Reinstalling the OS was the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for errors in Windows Event Viewer error log entries relevant to your application, and see if there are any mentions of third party DLLs in those errors.

OpenFileDialog is a low level component in Windows, so error messages are logged in Windows Event Viewer: "Windows Event Viewer" => "Windows Logs" => Application. Sort by date descending.

I had the same problem affecting our own Wpf application and also Notepad++. In Event Viewer I found an error mentioning our app, and it also mentioned a DLL belonging to a well known cloud storage provider. I uninstalled that provider's desktop application, and the problem went away.

It seems like the provider's plug-in to Windows Explorer was somehow breaking OpenFileDialog, but unfortunately I don't know exactly why that suddenly started happening.